# Perform operations on a dataframe from groupings by ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in Python:

| ID | maths | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | add | 12 |
| 1 | sub | 30 |
| 0 | add | 10 |
| 2 | mult | 3 |
| 0 | sub | 10 |
| 1 | add | 11 |
| 3 | sub | 40 |
| 2 | add | 21 |

My idea is to perform the following operations to get the result I want:

**First step:** Group the rows of the dataframe by ID. The order of the groups shall be indicated by the order of the original dataframe.

| ID | maths | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | add | 12 |
| 0 | add | 10 |
| 0 | sub | 10 |
| 1 | sub | 30 |
| 1 | add | 11 |
| 2 | mult | 3 |
| 2 | add | 21 |
| 3 | sub | 40 |

**Second step:** For each group created: Create a value for a new column 'result' where a mathematical operation indicated by the previous column of 'maths' is performed. If there is no previous row for the group, this column would have the value NaN.

| ID | maths | value | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | add | 12 | NaN |
| 0 | add | 10 | 22 |
| 0 | sub | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | sub | 30 | NaN |
| 1 | add | 11 | 19 |
| 2 | mult | 3 | NaN |
| 2 | add | 21 | 63 |
| 3 | sub | 40 | NaN |

**Third step:** Return the resulting dataframe.

I have tried to realise this code by making use of the pandas groupby method. But I have problems to iterate with conditions for each row and each group, and I don't know how to create the new column 'result' on a groupby object.

```
grouped_df = testing.groupby('ID')
  for key, item in grouped_df:
    print(grouped_df.get_group(key))
```

I don't know whether to use orderby or groupby or some other method that works for what I want to do. If you can help me with a better idea, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: the thing you did was order_by not group_by are you sure you need group_by? if yes then you've got to have aggregate functions on top of that

Comment: I didn't know about orderby, I'll try to use it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ID = list("00011223")
maths = ["add","add","sub","sub","add","mult","add","sub"]
value = [12,10,10,30,11,3,21,40]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ID,maths,value)),columns = ["ID","Maths","Value"])
df["Maths"] = df.groupby(["ID"]).pipe(lambda df:df.Maths.shift(1)).fillna("add")
df["Value1"] = df.groupby(["ID"]).pipe(lambda df:df.Value.shift(1))   
df["result"] = df.groupby(["Maths"]).pipe(lambda x:(x.get_group("add")["Value1"] + x.get_group("add")["Value"]).append(
    x.get_group("sub")["Value1"] - x.get_group("sub")["Value"]).append(
        x.get_group("mult")["Value1"] * x.get_group("mult")["Value"])).sort_index()
```

Here is the Output:

```
df
Out[168]: 
  ID Maths  Value  Value1  result
0  0   add     12     NaN     NaN
1  0   add     10    12.0    22.0
2  0   add     10    10.0    20.0
3  1   add     30     NaN     NaN
4  1   sub     11    30.0    19.0
5  2   add      3     NaN     NaN
6  2  mult     21     3.0    63.0
7  3   add     40     NaN     NaN
```